# $2$-Wasserstein distance between mixtures

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem. I have a discrete distribution $\mu_0$ (it is actually an empirical distribution). I have some $\mu_i$ (again discrete, some empirical distribution). I have some bound on the Wasserstein distance $W_2(\mu_0, \mu_i).$ I now want to consider a simple mixture of $\mu_i,$ that is, $\nu=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_i\mu_i$ where $\sum\lambda_i=1, \lambda_i>0.$

My goal is to bound $W_2^2(\mu_0, \nu).$ I felt that it would be easy to get a bound on $W_2^2(\mu_0, \nu)$ in terms of $W_2^2(\mu_0, \mu_i),$ but I am unable to prove anything. I want something like $$W_2^2(\mu_0, \nu)\le \sum \lambda_i^2 W_2^2(\mu_0, \mu_i).$$

This does not look terribly hard, but I am stuck. Can anyone please say if it is true or not? If anyone can give a simple demonstration of why this is true, it would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand\Ga{\Gamma}$ $\newcommand\ga{\gamma}$ $\newcommand\la{\lambda}$
Let $\Ga(\mu,\rho)$ denote the set of all measures with marginals $\mu$ and $\rho$. For each $i$, take any real $c_i>W_2(\mu_0,\mu_i)^2$, so that 
$$\int d(x,y)^2\ga_i(dx\times dy)<c_i$$ 
for some $\ga_i\in\Ga(\mu_0,\mu_i)$. Let 
$$\ga:=\sum_i\la_i\ga_i.$$
Then $\ga\in\Ga(\mu_0,\nu)$ and hence 
$$W_2(\mu_0,\nu)^2\le\int d(x,y)^2\ga(dx\times dy)
=\sum_i\la_i \int d(x,y)^2\ga_i(dx\times dy)<\sum_i\la_i c_i.$$ 
Letting now $c_i\downarrow W_2(\mu_0,\mu_i)^2$ for each $i$ such that $W_2(\mu_0,\mu_i)^2<\infty$, we get 
$$W_2(\mu_0,\nu)^2\le\sum_i\la_i W_2(\mu_0,\mu_i)^2.$$

---

The inequality you proposed, 
$$W_2(\mu_0,\nu)^2\le\sum_{i=1}^k\la_i^2 W_2(\mu_0,\mu_i)^2,\tag{1}$$ 
cannot hold in general. Indeed, suppose that for some probability measure $\rho$ we have $0<W_2(\mu_0,\rho)<\infty$. Let $\mu_i:=\rho$ and $\la_i:=1/k$ for all $i=1,\dots,k$. Then $\nu=\rho$ and the left-hand side of (1) is a constant $>0$, whereas its right-hand side goes to $0$ as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I realised that we can not hope for $\lambda_i^2$ in the right hand side. I could finally get the result with $\lambda_i$ but your argument is neater.

Comment: Also note that this argument works for any cost function!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this argument works for any mixtures in $W_2$ no?

Comment: @Dirk : That's right.

Comment: @Zorn'sLama : That's right.

Comment: Is this a well-known result?  That is, do you know a citeable reference to this?

Comment: @Elbebe : No, I don't know any reference to this. You can cite MathOverflow questions and answers by click on the "cite" buttons below them.

Comment: The argument should work for $W_p$ for any $p\in [1,\infty)$ no?

Comment: @BLBA : That's right.